# Webpack + Handlebars custom helper - require.extension not supported

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

So I have this little helper for text truncating

```
'use strict';
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

module.exports = function truncate(str, len, words) {
  var safe = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(str);
  var tooLong = safe.length > len;
  var s_ = tooLong ? safe.substr(0, len) : safe;
  if (words && tooLong) {
    var index = s_.lastIndexOf(' ');
    if (index !== -1) {
      s_ = s_.substr(0, index);
    }
  }
  return  new Handlebars.SafeString(tooLong ? s_ + ' &hellip;' : s_);
};
```

which throws three warnings in the console during compiling (but the output works as expected)

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js 22:38-56
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

WARNING in ./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js 23:2-20
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

WARNING in ./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js 24:2-20
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.
```

I googled and found I have to import handlebars in the helper in different way

```
import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars';
```

but this is much worse and throws errors

```
ERROR in Template execution failed: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

ERROR in   TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

So what's the right way to include handlebars for helpers. Or better way - how to include handlebars in webpack globally for all helpers which are using eg. `Handlebars.Utils`

Answer (score 1):

First of all in nodejs it is not possible to use `import` and `module.exports` in one file. To import something anyway you have to use `require`. Maybe this can help:

var Handlebars = require('handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars');

You can use [handlebars-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-webpack-plugin) to implement handlebars in webpack. But it is a lot of configuration to get it in.

Answer (score 1):

> I googled and found I have to import handlebars in the helper in different way
>
> ```js
> import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars';
> ```

That should also work, provided it's pointing to `handlebars.js`. In my case, I wrote:

```js
import * as Handlebars from '../../node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js';
```

###### The better way is to include this in your `webpack.config.js`.

```js
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'handlebars': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'handlebars', 'dist', 'handlebars.js'),
        }
    }
```

and keep using your import as normal in you code, like:

```js
import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars';
```